# How to make a thread wait until something happens without blocking the others

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I am making a barbershop simulation using threads in java. A barbershop consists of a waiting room with n chairs and a barber room with several barber chairs. If there are no customers to be served, the barber goes to sleep. If a customer enters the barbershop and all chairs are occupied, then the customer leaves the shop. If the barber is busy but chairs are available, then the customer sits in one of the free chairs. If the barber is asleep, the customer wakes up the barber.

My code so far is working well (I think) but with one mistake. Here the clients go to the barbershop after a random number of milliseconds, and can go there several times. The thing is that if a customer is already at the barbershop, it can't go there again until the service has finished, that means, I need to block the customer thread until the barber finishes cutting his hair, and that's where my code fails. I am pretty sure it must be done with wait() and notify() but when I do that I mess up the rest of threads, probably I am doing something wrong. So how can I sync that? Thanks in advance :)

Here is my code:

Main.java:

```
public class Main {

public static int tiempoSimulacion;

public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("ccia.labarberia");
static {
    logger.setLevel(Level.OFF)
    //logger.setLevel(Level.WARNING)
    ;}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int nBarberos = sc.nextInt();
    int nClientes = sc.nextInt();
    tiempoSimulacion = sc.nextInt();

    Cliente.distribucionNormal = new NormalDistribution(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt());

    Barbero.distribucionExponencial = new ExponentialDistribution(sc.nextInt());

    Barberia b = Barberia.getBarberia(); // La Barberia sigue el patrón Singleton

    Cliente.barberia = b;
    Barbero.barberia = b;
    b.setNumeroSillas(sc.nextInt());
    sc.close();

    Barbero[] barberos = new Barbero[nBarberos];
    for (int i=1; i<=nBarberos; i++){
        barberos[i-1] = new Barbero(i);
        barberos[i-1].start();
    }
    b.setBarberos(barberos);

    Thread[] clientes = new Thread[nClientes];
    for (int j=1; j<=nClientes; j++){
        clientes[j-1] = new Thread(new Cliente(j));
        clientes[j-1].start();
    }

    Thread.sleep(tiempoSimulacion*1000);

    for (int j=0; j<nClientes; j++){
        clientes[j].interrupt();
    }

    for (int i=0; i<nBarberos; i++){
        barberos[i].interrupt();
    }

    for (int j=0; j<nClientes; j++){
        clientes[j].join();
    }

    for (int i=0; i<nBarberos; i++){
        barberos[i].join();
    }


}

}
```

Client.java:

```
public class Cliente extends Thread{

public static Barberia barberia;
public static NormalDistribution distribucionNormal;

private int id;

public Cliente (int id) {
    this.id = id;
    System.out.println("El cliente " + id + " se ha creado.");
}

public int identificador() {
    return this.id;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try{
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long)distribucionNormal.sample() );
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

            }
            this.irABarberia();
        }
    }catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("El cliente " + this.id + " ha sido destruido.");
    }
}

public void irABarberia() throws InterruptedException{
    barberia.add(this);
}
}
```

Barber.java:

```
public class Barbero extends Thread{

private static final int OFFSET = 64;
public static Barberia barberia;
public static ExponentialDistribution distribucionExponencial;
private char id;

public Barbero(int i) {
    this.id = (char) (OFFSET + i); 
    System.out.println("El barbero " + this.id + " se ha creado.");
}

public char identificador() {
    return this.id;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
            barberia.cortarPelo(this);  
        } 
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println("El barbero " + this.id + " ha sido destruido.");
    }

}
}
```

Barbershop.java:

```
public class Barberia {

private static Barberia mBarberia;
private static int numSillas;
private Barbero[] barberos;
LinkedList<Cliente> listaClientes;

protected Barberia() {
    listaClientes = new LinkedList<Cliente>();
}

public static Barberia getBarberia() {
    if (mBarberia == null) {
        mBarberia = new Barberia();
    }
    return mBarberia;
}

public void setNumeroSillas(int sillas) {
    numSillas = sillas;
}

public void setBarberos(Barbero[] b) {
    this.barberos = new Barbero[b.length];
    for (int i=0; i<this.barberos.length; i++) {
        this.barberos[i] = b[i];
    }
}

public void cortarPelo(Barbero barbero) throws InterruptedException{

    Cliente cliente;
    synchronized (listaClientes) {
        while(listaClientes.size()==0) {
            System.out.println("El barbero " + barbero.identificador() + " se pone a dormir.");
            listaClientes.wait();
        }
        cliente = listaClientes.poll();

    }    
    System.out.println("El barbero " + barbero.identificador() + " atiende al cliente " + cliente.identificador() + ".");
    Thread.sleep((long)Barbero.distribucionExponencial.sample() );
    System.out.println("El barbero " + barbero.identificador() + " ha cortado el pelo al cliente " + cliente.identificador() + ".");

}

public void add (Cliente cliente) throws InterruptedException{
     System.out.println("El cliente " + cliente.identificador() + " llega a la barbería.");
     synchronized (listaClientes) {
         if(listaClientes.size() == numSillas) {
             System.out.println("El cliente " + cliente.identificador() + " se marcha sin ser atendido."); 
         } else {
             listaClientes.offer(cliente);

             if(listaClientes.size()>0 && listaClientes.size() <= barberos.length){
                 listaClientes.notify();
             } else {
                 System.out.println("El cliente " + cliente.identificador() + " se sienta en una silla de espera.");
             }  
         }    
     }
}
}
```

Comment: why don't you use join?

Comment: `wait()` and `notify()` are low-level primitive operations, and they are tricky to use properly.  Consider using a higher-level synchronization object instead.  Blocking queues can be very versatile.  For example, you could have the client wait for permission to get up from the chair by writing code to `take()` a token from a queue.  Then the barber thread could give the client permission by put()ting any object into the queue.

Answer (score -1):

What you want to achieve, you can do by using the synchronize feature. When several thread are synchronising the same object, java handle the behaviour you seek naturally :

- Only one thread can access the synchronized lock at a time. The
  others wait
- When the lock is free, all the waiting threads try to access it. No need to use wait, join or notify.

  Here is an example, implementing the behaviour you talked about : several clients trying to concurrently access the same seat of a barber shop.

The barbershop and main program :

```
public class BarberShop
{

// The main programm
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    // creating a Barbershopand its clients
    final BarberShop shop = new BarberShop();
    final BarberClient c1 = new BarberClient(shop, "Ian", 5);

    final BarberClient c2 = new BarberClient(shop, "Chewy", 10);

    final BarberClient c3 = new BarberClient(shop, "Luke", 3);

    // all clients Try to go to the barbershop concurrently
    c1.launchGoToBarberThread();
    c2.launchGoToBarberThread();
    c3.launchGoToBarberThread();

    // Example output :
    // Chewy Waiting for barbershop
    // Luke Waiting for barbershop
    // Ian Waiting for barbershop
    // Chewy Entered Barber shop at Fri Nov 27 14:32:38 CET 2015
    // Chewy Exiting Barber shop at Fri Nov 27 14:32:43 CET 2015
    // Ian Entered Barber shop at Fri Nov 27 14:32:43 CET 2015
    // Ian Exiting Barber shop at Fri Nov 27 14:32:45 CET 2015
    // Luke Entered Barber shop at Fri Nov 27 14:32:45 CET 2015
    // Luke Exiting Barber shop at Fri Nov 27 14:32:47 CET 2015

}
}
```

The clients synchronizing on the shop :

```
import java.util.Date;

// client class implementing the concurrency behaviour around the seat.
public class BarberClient
{

// the shop we synchronize on. Let's say it has only one seat and we synchronize on this.
private final BarberShop barberShop;

private final String     name;      // a name

private final int        beardSize; // the size of the beard to represent the time in the seat

private final Thread     thread;    // the thread that will actually be launched.

// constructor with name and beard size.
public BarberClient(final BarberShop pBarberShop,
                    final String pName,
                    final int pBeardSize)
{
    barberShop = pBarberShop;
    name = pName;
    beardSize = pBeardSize;

    // create the thread that just try to go to the barber...
    thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                goToBarber();

            } catch (final InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

// method concurrently trting to go to the shop
private void goToBarber() throws InterruptedException
{
    System.out.println(name + "\tWaiting for barbershop");// display client is waiting

    // Synchronize on the shop. It means you can seat only if nobody is on the seat. And waits for the seat
    // being free.
    synchronized (barberShop)
    {
        // We entered the synchronization block (= accessed to the seat).
        // NOBODY else can access the seat while we are here.

        // log enter, exit time, and wait for some time for the barber to do his job...
        System.out.println(name + "\tEntered Barber shop at " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        Thread.sleep(500 * beardSize);
        System.out.println(name + "\tExiting Barber shop at " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
    // now we have leave the synchronization block (and the seat). Anybody can go.
}

// method to launch the thread.
public void launchGoToBarberThread()
{
    thread.start();
}
}
```

I hope it helps you implement your behaviors.
Here you have some info about synchronization : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: No,  The purpose of a `synchronized` statement is to prevent two or more threads from accessing the same data at the same time.  If you want one thread to _wait_ for another thread to do something, then you could use the low-level primitives `o.wait()` and `o.notify() / o.notifyAll()`, but it would be better to use one of the higher-level synchronization objects (Queues, semaphores, barriers, etc.) that are defined in the `java.util.concurrent` package.